# googleapi: Error 400: Dataset myProject:myDataset is still in use, resourceInUse

Tags: go, google-api, google-bigquery

I am trying to remove dataset using BigQuery API.

I have no problem removing the dataset in question manually using BigQuery UI, however when I am using the API I am seeing the following error:

```
googleapi: Error 400: Dataset myProject:myDataset is still in use, resourceInUse
```

I have checked that there are no open connections using the dataset.

Here is the code used to remove dataset:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "context"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/jwt"
    "google.golang.org/api/bigquery/v2"
)



func main() {
    var authConfig *jwt.Config
    var projectID = "myProject"
    var datasetID = "myDataset"
    ctx := context.Background()
    oauthClient := oauth2.NewClient(ctx, authConfig.TokenSource(ctx))
    service, err := bigquery.New(oauthClient)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = service.Datasets.Delete(projectID , datasetID).Context(ctx).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there still tables or views inside the dataset? You probably need to delete them first.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a dataset that contains tables and/or views, you have two options:

- Delete each table and view, then delete the dataset.
- Delete the dataset directly, passing `true` for the `deleteContents` option. This will delete all tables and views in the dataset.

Comment: Had the same kind of error and removing the tables fixed the issue ! It's a matter of removing smaller pieces (tables, views) first.